# How to download sap.ui.table.Table data to xlsx format

Tags: sapui5

I am having sap ui Table and I want to download data in XLSX format without any delimiters, I am able to download in XLS format with tab delimiter.

```js
onDownload: sap.ui.table.Table.prototype.exportData ||  function() {
  oBusy.open();
  var that = this;
  this.getView().addStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact");
  var tabId = this.getView().byId("table_id");
  var tableData = tabId.getModel().getData();
  var Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  var aExpData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    if (tableData[i].Select) {
      for (var j = 0; j < oArrTableModel.length; j++) {
        if (tableData[i].EBELN === oArrTableModel[j].EBELN) {
          ExpData.push(PushData);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  jModel.setData(/*set data*/);
  var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({
    exportType: new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
      //File Extension Provided as XLS
      fileExtension: "xls",
      separatorChar: "\t",
      mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
      charset: "utf-8",
    }),
    models: jModel,
    rows: {
      path: "/"
    },
    columns: [
      {
        name: "Change Indicator",
        template: {
          content: "{INDICATOR}"
        }
      },
      {
        name: "PO No",
        template: {
          content: "{EBELN}"
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  oBusy.close();
},
```

Comment: There's built in stuff for excel that might be easier:  https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/entity/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet/sample/sap.ui.export.sample.json) example can help you.

`sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet` creates a new spreadsheet export object. Use this object to build and download a spreadsheet file in Office Open XML Spreadsheet format from tabular data. This functionality is normally used together with UI5 tables.